# contract violation in my implementation of "map"

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm beginning in Scheme (actually, Racket with DrRacket) and I want to practice by implementing a map function (apply a function to all elements of a list), but there's something wrong that I don't understand.
(I have, aside from my imperative background, a basic knowledge of haskell)

I want to translate the following piece of haskell (Just to show the algorithm) :

```
map f [] = []
map f x:xs = (f x) : (map f xs)
```

Here's my code :

```
(define (map f xs)

  (if (= xs '()) '() ; if list is empty, return empty list
      (cons (f (car xs)) (map f (cdr xs))))

  )
```

To test it, I used this :

```
(define (testFunction x) (+ x 1))
(define testList '(1 2 3 4 5))
(map testFunction testList)
```

And I get the following error :

> =: contract violation
>   expected: number ?
>   given : '(1 2 3 4 5)
>   argument position: 1st
>   other arguments...:

which highlights the predicate (= xs '())

Any tips ?

Comment: It might be more schemey to implement map in terms of fold.

Comment: @amirouche : yup, I figured it out later while reading abput haskell. And it's more performant due to tail call optimization, isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using DrRacket, then for that condition, simply use (empty?):

```
(if (empty? xs)
    xs ; because xs is empty
    ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Is it really impossible to return empty list ?

Comment: The issue isn't that its returning an empty list, `'()` is fine. The problem is the fact that you were using `=`

Answer (score 3):

The [`=`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._~3d%29%29) function is specifically for equality between numbers. It has special handling for numeric values by handling comparisons between exact and inexact numbers. In general, though, for non-numeric equality, you should use the [`equal?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._equal~3f%29%29) predicate:

```
> (equal? '() '())
#t
```

In this particular case, as mentioned by [Raghav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6475173/raghav), you can also use [`empty?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._empty~3f%29%29) or [`null?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._null~3f%29%29) to test for the empty list (the [`empty?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._empty~3f%29%29) predicate is just an alias for [`null?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._null~3f%29%29)).

Answer (score 3):

Wow - a few others already beat me to it, but I'll share my answer, anyways.

Your issue stems from your use of `=` to test list emptiness.

From the `=` in [the docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._~3c~3d%29%29):

> Returns #t if all of the arguments are numerically equal, #f
>   otherwise.

In order to get your program working, I'd suggest using `equal?` to test the two lists for equality or, better yet, use `empty?` or `null?` to test if `xs` is an empty list. (I hope you don't take offense, but I've also massaged the code into what's (arguably) more idiomatic Scheme).

```
(define (mymap f xs)
  (if (empty? xs)
    xs
    (cons 
      (f (car xs))
      (mymap f (cdr xs)))))

(define (test-function x) (+ x 1))
(define test-list (list 1 2 3 4))

(mymap test-function test-list)
```

Comment: Thanks for indent, I had never thought about it until now. I guess it's time to do so :)

Comment: You shouldn't use `eq?` to test whether lists are equal, because it won't work properly on anything other than empty lists. You should use `equal?` instead for two arbitrary lists, or`empty?` or `null?` for testing whether a list you have is empty.